# Connection refused to Schema Registry

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I have installed the new version of confluent i.e 5.4 and since after that I am unable to connect to the confluent, my schema registry also gets terminated untimely.

Today when I started the confluent and tried to produce the data, I recieved the following error:

```
    2020-03-05 12:25:00,453] ERROR Failed to send HTTP request to endpoint: http://localhost:8081/subjects/avro-key/versions (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService:245)
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
    at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:177)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:474)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:569)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:341)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:362)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1248)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1187)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1081)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:1015)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1362)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1337)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:241)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:322)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:422)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:414)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:400)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.registerAndGetId(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:140)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.register(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:196)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.register(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:172)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.serializeImpl(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:71)
    at io.confluent.kafka.formatter.AvroMessageReader.readMessage(AvroMessageReader.java:199)
    at kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer$.main(ConsoleProducer.scala:55)
    at kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer.main(ConsoleProducer.scala)'
```

**Updated the question with the Schema-registry logs:**

```
    INFO Logging initialized @865ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog (org.eclipse.jetty.util.log:169)
[2020-03-09 12:35:51,851] INFO Adding listener: http://0.0.0.0:8081 (io.confluent.rest.ApplicationServer:316)
[2020-03-09 12:35:52,366] INFO Created schema registry namespace localhost:2181 /schema_registry (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryConfig:709)
[2020-03-09 12:35:53,329] INFO Initializing KafkaStore with broker endpoints: PLAINTEXT://LAP-LIN-897:9092 (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStore:108)
[2020-03-09 12:38:03,215] ERROR Error starting the schema registry (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryRestApplication:77)
io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.exceptions.SchemaRegistryInitializationException: Error initializing kafka store while initializing schema registry
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry.init(KafkaSchemaRegistry.java:248)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryRestApplication.initSchemaRegistry(SchemaRegistryRestApplication.java:75)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryRestApplication.configureBaseApplication(SchemaRegistryRestApplication.java:90)
        at io.confluent.rest.Application.configureHandler(Application.java:217)
        at io.confluent.rest.ApplicationServer.doStart(ApplicationServer.java:185)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryMain.main(SchemaRegistryMain.java:43)
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.exceptions.StoreInitializationException: Timed out trying to create or validate schema topic configuration
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStore.createOrVerifySchemaTopic(KafkaStore.java:177)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStore.init(KafkaStore.java:119)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry.init(KafkaSchemaRegistry.java:246)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await(KafkaFutureImpl.java:108)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:272)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStore.createOrVerifySchemaTopic(KafkaStore.java:170)
        ... 8 more
```

'

Comment: localhost:8081 is not running!

Comment: My port is running, but it is not accepting it. I have even tried to restart my pc, but nothing works. Also, my schema-registry gets down anytime. For instance, I start the confluent and try to produce messages, and the next moment the control-center and Schema registry get down.

Comment: Can you please try curl? Can you please show the logs of starting up the registry?

Comment: Clearly the registry isn't starting... It's failing to connect to Kafka at `PLAINTEXT://LAP-LIN-897:9092`

Comment: @cricket_007 I know that it is not starting, but this only happened after I updated the confluent.

Comment: I doubt an update broke it. I've ran updates before just fine. Please show your `server.properties` file. In particular, set `listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092` in that file, and try again